# Error in docker: network "path" declared as external, but could not be found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I have been assigned with a task that uses Docker container for development. I followed the tutorial for installing the Docker and the containers on Windows 10, but I have the following error: `network remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network declared as external, but could not be found`

The steps I've done so far are:

1. Cloned the repository from GitHub.
2. Installed Docker on my laptop.
3. Once I installed Docker, I went in the root of my project and ran the following command. `docker-compose build -d -t docker-compose.yml` - docker-compose.yml being the file in the root dir.
4. I opened Docker app and I ran the images created.
5. I ran the command `docker-compose up`. When I ran this command, the error I specified at the beginning appears. `network remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network declared as external, but could not be found`

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    ui:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network

    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        networks:
            - remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network
networks:
    remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network:
        external: true
```

Ran: `docker ps -a`

```
ID              IMAGE
5e6cf997487c   remaxmd-site_ui:latest      
451009e0a2a6   redis:alpine                
85e7cde67d05   docmer-compose.yml:latest
```

I might do something wrong here. Can somebody help me? I much appreciate your time!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I solved the issue, finally. The issue came from the fact that I had in docker-compose.yml `remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network` declared as external. The external network was not created during installation, thus I needed to create a bridging network.
I ran the command `docker network create "name_of_network"`

For further details, here is the full documentation [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

Comment: thanks, how dod you use "name_of_network" in the docker-compose? was it remaxmdcrm_remaxmd-network or was it something else?

Comment: in my case, indeed. I used the name of the declared external network. @Thomas

Comment: thanks - I read a bit too quickly but I'm on a Mac (and you mention Windows) and it seems that docker desktop deactivates this feature on Mac

Answer (score 16):

You shouldn't have to run a command to create the network prior to running `docker compose`, Docker should create the network if it doesn't exist. The reason you're getting this error is because you're declaring the network as external, which means that Docker expects it to already exist. If you need a new one, remove `external: true`

Comment: Hi @Peter, thanks for the info brought here ! You are right that docker should create bridges automatically when ```docker-compose``` is executed. However, in my case, I had an user-defined network.Hence the reason I did not remove it. As docs said, it is better user-defined bridges to be explicitly created between containers. Main reason is: ```Using a user-defined network provides a scoped network in which only containers attached to that network are able to communicate.```  In my case, it was between ```db``` and ```web```. Nevertheless, your answer is legit indeed.

Comment: @geekt that's correct, you want a user-defined network, you create it in `networks` section. You only use `external: true` if you have another network, defined elsewhere, already running.

Answer (score 5):

You can see `docker network ls` and uses `bridge` network